# Python group by data from a column to a row in a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, associations

Hello great Python coders,
Could you please help me out with this
I am trying to get the data from Items column to put them in separate columns for doing Association rule, the purpose should be getting a new data frame whose columns are items purchased together by a customer in the same date

**Data now looks like:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVjc2.png)

**I would expect to get the data that looks like**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YdWz.png)
...

Thank you so much! I hope to receive your comments

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check `pivot` , all you missing is the key for column which can be created by the `groupby` with `cumcount`

```
out = df.assign(key = df.groupby('id').cumcount()).pivot('id','key','Items')
Out[46]: 
key                 0       1
id                           
1249       citrusruit  coffee
1381             curd    soda
1440  othervegetables  yogurt
```